# Transform <G> with setNativeProps possible with react-native-svg?

Tags: svg, react-native

I posted this as an issue in the react-native-svg repo, but it's more of a question than an issue. I should have posted it here from start.

I need to move and scale individual`<G>` (group) elements with setNativeProps. Nothing I've tried seems to work.

I tried:

```
setNativeProps({x: newX, y: newY})

setNativeProps({x: newX.toString(), y: newY.toString()})

setNativeProps({transform: [{translateX: newX}, {translateY: newY}])
```

If I use setNativeProps directly on a `<Circle>` for example, everything works fine.

- Does `G` implement setNativeProps?
- What syntax should I use for setting scale and position on a group?

Comment: You sure that's <Group>? in SVG the group element is <g>

Comment: Good catch. It should be <G>. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [VirtualNode (android)](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/blob/f32800bfbd90cf40765083eb42ced567bb910f5a/android/src/main/java/com/horcrux/svg/VirtualNode.java#L175) and [RNSVGNode (ios)](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/blob/04887af278c49a0fa3b7956d2992fb2e71efd279/ios/RNSVGNode.m#L128) implementations have setMatrix methods.
Give new property values by sending a column-major array representation of a [transform matrix definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) over the bridge. As in:

```
setNativeProps({ matrix: [scaleX, skewY, skewX, scaleY, translateX, translateY] })
```

Comment: Isn't this just a repeat of the information in the OPs answer from 5 hours before this?

Comment: I asked him to post here so I could accept his answer. Didn’t feel right to accept my own answer because it is not my own.

Comment: @msand Your solution works fine. I'm now on an FPS-hunt.. Would it be better (or even possible) to set the Svg viewbox via setNativeProps? I.e. would it be faster than transforming a child G, and would I gain optimization in form of automatic clipping of elements outside of the viewbox?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `setNativeProps` will re-render the entire subtree of your G component (read [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html)).

What you could do instead is make the properties of your `<G>` element dependent on your component's state like this:

`<G x={this.state.myXPos} y={this.state.myYPos}/>`

Comment: <g> elements in SVG do not possess x or y attributes or properties, setting a transform is what would be required.

Comment: If I wrap my Svg in a View, the Svg and all of its child objects are transformed when I use setNativeProps on the View. But I'd rather not sprinkle my main View with a bunch of Svg objects, mostly because of a leak in react-native-svg (will probably be fixed), but it also seems much nicer to have one screen sized Svg and a bunch of groups which I transform when needed. I could proxy setNativeProps to do what's needed with the child objects, but transforming the group would be neater.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer in the recat-native-svg repo from Mikael Sand (maybe @msand ?).

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/556#issuecomment-354099452

This works great:

```
setNativeProps({ matrix: [scaleX, skewY, skewX, scaleY, translateX, translateY] })
```

The transformation is performed on all objects in the group, i.e. exactly what I wanted.